# how expend horizontally an absolute div still 400px and then add line-break

Tags: css

I want to use this css for tooltip: [enter link description here](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) but i want that the hint have a max width of 400px. if i set max-width:400px and remove white-space:nowrap then the width will be always very short (their is a line break on every word). how to specify that the hint can expend horizontally still 400px and then only add line break ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions for this.  The first is to add the following to ".hint:after, [data-hint]:after"

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 400px;
```

As you already surmised, you must remove the "whitespace: nowrap" as well

If for some reason you can't do that, you can also set the "display" property to "table".

Comment: no it's not work :( :( when i set with:100% it's take the width of the container of the absolute hint :(

Comment: did you try "display: table"?